# How to get Unique Key and Not Null column Name in Oracle11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints, database-metadata

For constraint validation i want to read unique key and not null column from oracle11g, I could able to retrieve same from Mysql but don't know how to do it in Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join `[DBA|ALL|USER]_CONSTRAINTS` view with `[DBA|ALL|USER]_CONS_COLUMNS` view.

**NOT NULL** constraint is type `C`.
**UNIQUE** constraint is type `U`.

```
SELECT a.table_name,
  b.column_name,
  a.constraint_type
FROM dba_constraints a
JOIN dba_cons_columns b
ON a.owner             = b.owner
AND a.constraint_name  = b.constraint_name
AND a.table_name       = b.table_name
AND a.owner            ='<user_name>'
AND a.constraint_type IN ('U', 'C');
```

Comment: Using above query i could able to see <table name > where unique key and not null is applied, but i want to retrieve actual <column name> on which these constraint are applied ? Please let me know how i will do so..

Comment: Ok, I modified the answer. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Comment: @KUNALSHARMA You're welcome!